# TypeScript Defining Type For Bunch Of Constructor Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I have the following code and I am wondering if I can improve it more efficiently with interface to reduce constructor properties' type declaration in the class:

```
class sample {
sample1: string;
sample2: string;
sample3: number;
sample4: string[];
sample5: string;
sample6: string;
sample7: number;
sample8: string[];
sample9: string;
sample10: string;
sample11: number;
sample12: string[];

constructor (){
this.sample1= ''
this.sample2= ''
this.sample3= 2
this.sample4= [x,y,z]
this.sample5= ''
this.sample6= ''
this.sample7= 0
this.sample8= [a,b,c,d]
this.sample9= ''
this.sample10= 'sample';
this.sample11= 1;
this.sample12= [some,sample,text];
}

setSampleMethod = (text) => {
this.sample10 = text

}


}
```

Comment: You can initialize the properties here itself `class sample { sample1: string = ''; sample2: string = '';` etc

Comment: @adiga Did you mean removing all constructor properties from constructor body and initializing them in type declaration?

Comment: Yes. Like this: [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20sample%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sample1%3A%20string%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample2%3A%20string%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample3%3A%20number%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample4%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22x%22%2C%20%22y%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: and can we summarize these props. in another interface file to reduce line of code?

Comment: You can create an interface and have your class implement that interface. But initializing part you'd have to do that in your class anyway. You can't intialize in an interface

Comment: [Something like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20sample%20implements%20ISample%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sample1%20%3D%20%2210%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample2%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample3%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample4%20%3D%20%5B%22x%22%2C%20%22y%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISample%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sample1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample3%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20sample4%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for interface, you can create a model class with getters/setters defined in it, and extend that model into your class.

Please go through below StackBlitz for the sample code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elss2i

Here you can see, I've also moved the default values into constructor's parameters. This will help you to pass parameters to the constructor whenever required.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what if I am going to use model class for react class component. I think it is impossible to extends react class from model class since it should be inherited from react.Component class